# How to align the nav items to right using the Yii2 widget Nav::Widget

Tags: yii2, alignment, navbar

Hello i used the default NabBar widget in Yii2 basic template

```
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top']
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'Applications', 'url' => ['/form-applications/index']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest
            ? ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
            : '<li class="nav-item">'
                . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
                . Html::submitButton(
                    'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
                )
                . Html::endForm()
                . '</li>'
    ]
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

and this is the result

[default navbar yii2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gxyG.png)

i need pull right only the items nav and the brand company stay left side.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this, add this class css ms-auto

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right ms-auto'],
    ...
```